# Trying to use match and gmatch string pattern matching functions in lua to parse an xml file but not getting the expected result

Tags: xml, parsing, lua, lua-patterns

I want to parse and print specific data from an XML file using Lua.

Here is a snippet from my XML code:

```
<Service>
<NewInstance ref="E961625723F5FDC8BD550077282E074C">
<Std>DiscoveredElement</Std>
<Key>E961625723F5FDC8BD550077282E074C</Key>
<Attributes>
<Attribute name="TARGET_TYPE" value="j2ee_application" />
<Attribute name="AppType" value="ear" />
<Attribute name="TARGET_GUID" value="E961625723F5FDC8BD550077282E074C" />
<Attribute name="TARGET_NAME"
value="/Farm_b2b4_sys20_b2b4_domain/b2b4_domain/WLS_B2B4a/worklistapp" />
</Attributes>
</NewInstance>
<NewInstance ref="FD8A116D5C8DD2332B024BCBD6A81BD8">
<Std>DiscoveredElement</Std>
<Key>FD8A116D5C8DD2332B024BCBD6A81BD8</Key>
<Attributes>
<Attribute name="TARGET_TYPE" value="composite" />
<Attribute name="SERVICE_TYPE" value="" />
<Attribute name="TARGET_NAME" value="LAB-DB-B-AIX-Grp" />
<Attribute name="TARGET_GUID" value="FD8A116D5C8DD2332B024BCBD6A81BD8" />
</Attributes>
</NewInstance>
</Service>
```

From this XML file I want to display the value of TARGET_TYPE and TARGET_NAME corresponding to every `NewInstance` ref tag in the file

I tried it in 2 ways -
Lua code 1 :

```
local file = io.open("sample.xml", "rb")   -- Open file for reading (binary data)
for instance in file:read("*a"):gmatch("<NewInstance ref=\"(.-)\">") do  -- Read whole file content and iterate through attribute matches

TARGET_TYPE = instance:gmatch('TARGET_TYPE.-value=\"(.-)\"')
TARGET_NAME = instance:gmatch('TARGET_NAME.-value=\"(.-)\"')
print("New Instance :", instance)
print("Target Type : ",TARGET_TYPE)
print("Target Name : ",TARGET_NAME)
end
file:close()
```

The output that I get for this is -

```
New Instance :  E961625723F5FDC8BD550077282E074C
Target Type :   function: 0050E9C0
Target Name :   function: 0050EA10
New Instance :  FD8A116D5C8DD2332B024BCBD6A81BD8
Target Type :   function: 0050EA60
Target Name :   function: 0050EAB0
Exit code: 0
```

It is picking up some random values for target name and target type.

Lua code 2 :

```
local file = io.open("sample.xml", "rb")   -- Open file   for reading (binary data)
for instance in file:read("*a"):gmatch("<NewInstance ref=\"(.-)\">") do
TARGET_TYPE = instance:match('TARGET_TYPE.-value="(.-)"')
TARGET_NAME = instance:match('TARGET_NAME.-value="(.-)"')
print("New Instance :", instance)
print("Target Type : ",TARGET_TYPE)
print("Target Name : ",TARGET_NAME)
end
file:close()
```

This gives the output:

```
lua -e "io.stdout:setvbuf 'no'" "prac.lua" 
New Instance :  E961625723F5FDC8BD550077282E074C
Target Type :   nil
Target Name :   nil
New Instance :  FD8A116D5C8DD2332B024BCBD6A81BD8
Target Type :   nil
Target Name :   nil
Exit code: 0
```

Please suggest a way to retrieve the required and correct attribute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's not a great idea to use Lua pattern (or regex) to parse XML. Instead, use a XML parser.

Anyway, for this particular problem, the first code doesn't work because `gmatch` is an iterator, it's not supposed to be used like that.

For the second code, the pattern `<NewInstance ref=\"(.-)\">` captures only the `ref=` part, you should instead capture the part between `<NewInstance ref=` and `</NewInstance>`:

```
for instance in xml:gmatch("<NewInstance ref=\".-\">(.-)</NewInstance>") do
```